# How to prevent LeakCanary from reporting this AOSP's InputMethodManager leak?

Tags: android, memory-leaks, leakcanary

In my Application class I have tried to ignore all the leaks of AOSP using the following code:

```
LeakCanary.install(this, null, AndroidExcludedRefs.createAppDefaults().build());
```

But that does not prevent the below mentioned `InputMethodManager` leak from being reported. I am doing it wrong or such an operation is not supported

```
D/LeakCanary: In myapp:0.1.25-SNAPSHOT:12500.
D/LeakCanary: * EXCLUDED LEAK.
D/LeakCanary: * myapp.ui.activities.HomeActivity has leaked:
D/LeakCanary: * GC ROOT static android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.sInstance
D/LeakCanary: * references android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.mCurRootView , matching exclusion field android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager#mCurRootView
D/LeakCanary: * references com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.mContext
D/LeakCanary: * leaks myapp.ui.activities.HomeActivity instance
D/LeakCanary: * Retaining: 3.8KB.
```